# What is that invisible bump in the air called that occurs after completing a 360 degree turn?

Tags: aerodynamics, terminology

Does that bump you feel after completing a level 360 degree turn in an airplane have a proper name? I've heard it called an "attaboy bump", but obviously thats not a proper name.

My understanding is that the bump occurs when a properly executed level 360 turn overlaps the disturbed air caused by the same aircraft's flight path into the turn.

Comment: Loss of separation with the next aircraft in approach?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's your aircraft's *[wake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake)*, as in [wake turbulence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_turbulence).

Comment: Yes. I think I worded my question wrong, but do you know if there is a name for intersecting your own aircraft's wake upon completion of a 360 degree turn?

Comment: @Devil07 I've never heard a special name for it, everyone I know just says "I hit my own wake"

Comment: me too, I was wondering if it had a special name. I say we hereby name it the "attaboy bump", unless you can think of a more appropriate one. ;)

Comment: Well, I had it flip me over once, so it was an oh s*@t bump then.

Comment: @GdD what kind of aircraft were you in?

Comment: It was a Cessna 172, I was practicing steep turns @Devil07

Comment: Wow, 8 words, 18 votes. That looks like a record which will hold a long time :-)